# Backup software options for a preschool

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, backup

What are some options for a good file backup software? Online storage is not an option (budget).

Should be free, lightweight, support scheduling, incremental backups but first and foremost offer encryption. They have photos of children and personal documents that must be protected.

They have one pc that runs on XP but they're upgrading their hardware and switch to 7 soon.
They're using Uranium Backup now but say it's too slow.

Comment: what're you planning on backing up *to*?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek a 2TB hard drive.

Comment: I suggest you verify the software is still slow on their new hardware, my guess, its slow because they are using decade old hardware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any regular backup software, but back up to an encrypted drive. This divorces copying and encryption into two independent steps and, *most importantly*, safeguards your from getting locked into backup's vendor encryption.

One option is to back up to an external USB drive that is formatted as an encrypted disk with [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/). When you are ready to run your backup, you plug the disk in and mount it to a drive letter from TrueCrypt interface (includes entering the password). This creates an additional drive that looks and works as a regular disk, but behind the scenes all information going to/from it is transparently encrypted/decrypted, so it is always stored encrypted. Then you just run your backup straight to this mounted drive. When done - unmount and disconnect the disk.